# ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.appcompat:design:1.0.2

Tags: android

whenever i try to implement design dependency it gives an configuration error . Error unresolved .
here's the configuration i have

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.loginform"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:design:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Any idea what could be the possible reason?

Comment: `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`

Comment: Just remove implementation 'androidx.appcompat:design:1.0.2' from build.gradle

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Instead of

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:design:1.0.2'
```